# Usage of nw_interface_radio_type_t？

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, networking

I want to use path_monitor in Network.framework to monitor changes in network status. There is an enumeration definition `nw_interface_radio_type_t` in `interface.h` of Network.framework. I have not found how to use it.

我想用Network.framework中path_monitor来监听网络状态的变化，在Network.framework的interface.h中有一个枚举定义nw_interface_radio_type_t，我没有找到关于它的使用方法。

开发环境：
Objective-C
iOS13+
Xcode15.3
M1 Mac

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpathmonitor/2998734-init